# I dont know how to return the result of plus and minus in my React calculator

Tags: reactjs

I have built a simple calculator that adds and subtracts the numbers you put in but i don't know how I can display the result. Here is my code :

```
**import React, { useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(0);
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(0);
  const [sub, setSub] = useState(0);
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(0);
  function plus() {
    setSub(number1+number2)
  }
  function minus() {
    setSub(number1-number2)
  }
  return(
    <div className="App">
      Result = {sub} <br />
      <input placeholder="0" value= {Number(number1)} onChange={(e) => setNumber1(e.target.value)} />
      <input placeholder="0" value= {Number(number2)} onChange={(e) => setNumber2(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Solution 1

1. You can use a single state variable (let's say `result`) to keep track of the result.
2. I would suggest to use number inputs (`type="number"`)
3. And then don't forget to cast your inputs to `Number` in the click handlers.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(0);
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(0);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  const num1 = Number(number1);
  const num2 = Number(number2);

  function plus() {
    setResult(num1 + num2);
  }

  function minus() {
    setResult(num1 - num2);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Result = {result} <br />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="0"
        value={Number(number1)}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="0"
        value={Number(number2)}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={plus}> + </button> <button onClick={minus}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

###### Solution 2

You can also checkout the solution below that uses a single handler, this will allow you to add more operations later in the future.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(0);
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(0);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  function handleCalculation(operation) {
    const num1 = Number(number1);
    const num2 = Number(number2);

    switch (operation) {
      case "add":
        setResult(num1 + num2);
        break;
      case "subtract":
        setResult(num1 - num2);
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Operation ${operation} not supported`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Result = {result} <br />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="0"
        value={number1}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="0"
        value={number2}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => handleCalculation("add")}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleCalculation("subtract")}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @JUSUF Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Solved the issue thanks!

Comment: @JUSUF Glad that I could help. If this solved your problem, you can consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

input text is a string so you are concat string and don't calculate sum
you need to cast the string to a float for exemple
your code will look like that

```js
export default function App() {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState(0);
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState(0);
  const [sub, setSub] = useState(0);

  function plus() {
    setSub(parseFloat(number1) + parseFloat(number2));
  }
  function minus() {
    setSub(parseFloat(number1) - parseFloat(number2));
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Result = {sub} <br />
      <input
        placeholder="0"
        value={Number(number1)}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber1(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="0"
        value={Number(number2)}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber2(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could also wrap Number() around the e.target.value

Comment: @KeatonBenning you are absolutely right. Cast the event before setting state is better to avoid redendant code